Why did Dronacharya ji accept Drishtadyumna as a disciple?
Why did Dronacharya ji accept Drishtadyumna as a disciple when he was meant to kill him? What does Mahabharata say?

Drona knew that destiny cannot be changed. So he wanted to make sure that even if Dhrishtadyumna does kill him, it will be because of his own teachings.

And the great Drona, bringing the Pancala prince into his own abode,
taught him all weapons in requital of half the kingdom he had formerly
taken from Drupada. The high-souled son of Bharadvaja, regarding
destiny to be inevitable, did what would perpetuate his own great
deeds.'"


CLXIX, Chaitraratha parva, Mahabharata.

